# Hibernate not getting manually INSERTed object

Tags: sql, hibernate, jsp

I was given a pre-created project that uses Hibernate and was asked to add some features to it.

The database it came with has a user table and there is a login servlet page that uses hibernate to log in a user with provided credentials.

To get the very first user in the DB I manually INSERTed it with an SQL tool.  Now when I try to log in using those credentials it fails.  Is there anything extra I need to do to be able to use that manually added user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, to read existing data, there's nothing that needs to be done to the row itself in the database to make Hibernate read it. Your problem is one of a myriad of other possibilities, such as your Hibernate being configured to read from some other database or table, or encountering an error that you need to go find in the log.

Comment: Okay.  I looked at the log and there is no error.  Hibernate is correctly set up because it is correctly pulling data from other tables.  I understand you probably can't help that well without having access the the project.  Thanks for your help.